# using variable inside COPY FROM statement postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to store a path in a variable, to use it in a Copy statement, but
it is not working.

```
DO $$ 

DECLARE PATH char(100):='/home/gabriela/Documents/q_types.csv';

BEGIN

  CREATE TABLE mydbschema.example(

    ID integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,

    Value char(15) NOT NULL 
    );

  COPY mydbschema.example FROM 'PATH' DELIMITER ',';

END $$;
```

Comment: COPY mydbschema.example FROM PATH DELIMITER ','; didnt work either

Answer (score 1):

```
create or replace function load(file_name text)
returns void as $$
Declare
 csv_path text:= '/home/gabriela/Documents/';
 t_path text:=csv_path||file_name;

begin
    -- copy the data from csv file
    execute format('copy example from %L with delimiter '','' quote ''}'' csv', t_path);
end;

$$ language plpgsql;

DO $$ BEGIN
    PERFORM load('example.csv');
END $$;
```